# What is PyQGIS equivalent code of expression "attribute(@atlas_feature, 'FIELD_NAME')"?

Tags: pyqgis

I have a pretty long expression filter so it would be more neat to put it all in a function expression instead. So far, I just found that equivalent PyQGIS within function body tends to be ironically even longer, though.

I'm trying to find equivalent expression in PyQGIS of

```
attribute(@atlas_feature, 'FIELD_NAME')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@atlas_feature` is a variable which is provided in the expression context from the environment. Such variables are normally passed as parameters into functions, just like you are passing it here as a parameter to a function `attribute`.

You can do the same in your own function which then looks like this:

```
@qgsfunction(args=1, group='shorthands')
def get_atlas_attribute(atlasfeature, feature, parent):
    return atlasfeature['FIELD_NAME']
```

And you would call it like this

```
get_atlas_attribute(@atlas_feature)
```

I am not sure if this is of big help for you just as well as I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve.

I guess it's mostly about making your expressions more readable by delegating repeated code to a dedicated function. I think that's fine (although it adds another layer of potential failures).

> I just found that equivalent PyQGIS within function body tends to be ironically even longer

That is very likely to be true. And I don't think there is anything ironic about it. The expression engine is built for this very purpose. Take yet another language and you will have even more code ;)

Comment: Can I have like `get_atlas_attribute()`?  I'd like that expression function figure `@atlas_feature` out on its own. Is it possible?

Comment: Possibly yes, based on [the register_function code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/core/__init__.py#L41) but overwriting [funcV2 instead of func](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/core/__init__.py#L75) where you get a [expression context instead of a feature as parameter](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master_2/src/core/qgsexpression.h#L598-L601).

Comment: Okey. I'd like to pass @atlas_feature more than any deeper route then.
Anyway, I've still not got what it is supposed to.

`atlasfeature['FIELD_NAME']`

`Eval Error:
list indices must be integers, not str`

It looks like expression calculator sees atlasfeature as some kind of collections.
Is atlasfeature passed down here actually QT.Variant? (seen on other questions)
If so, how do I cast it back as a QGIS feature?

Comment: I guess I'm getting closer but still not there.

`QgsFeature(atlasfeature).attribute('FIELD_NAME')`

`Eval Error:
'FIELD_NAME'`

This leaves me stoned. What's next to do then?

Comment: Sidenote: this will be much easier with QGIS 3, where the expression context is always there ;) Does `atlasfeature[0]['FIELD_NAME']` work?

Comment: Not working in all 3 args-settings.

When `args='auto'`, `atlasfeature[0]['FIELD_NAME']`

`Eval Error:
'0'`

When `args=1`, `atlasfeature[0]['FIELD_NAME']`

`Eval Error:
'FIELD_NAME'`

When `args=-1`, `atlasfeature[0]['FIELD_NAME']`

`Eval Error:
'FIELD_NAME'`